# Error(56,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: php

```
CURSOR acct_cur (v_sol VARCHAR2)
      IS WITH ibank_adept_table1 as (SELECT cost_type , amount,TO_NUMBER(case when turnover in('.','shoukeen') then null
      else TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(turnover,'#N/A'),'N'),' '),','),CHR(9))) end) turnover, ACCT_NUMBER
      FROM dailymis.IBANK_ADEPT_TABLE WHERE del_flg='N') ,
```

Getting Error in above statement
need resolution

Answer (score 1):

`WITH` clause cannot be used inside a cursor declaration.

Take look into the code below without `WITH` clause:

```
CURSOR acct_cur (v_sol VARCHAR2) IS
  SELECT cost_type, amount,
         TO_NUMBER(CASE WHEN turnover IN ('.', 'shoukeen') THEN NULL
                       ELSE TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(turnover, '#N/A'), 'N'), ' '), ','), CHR(9)))
                  END) turnover, 
         ACCT_NUMBER 
  FROM dailymis.IBANK_ADEPT_TABLE 
  WHERE del_flg = 'N';
```